# How to connect to MySQL from Python (3)?

Tags: python, mysql, pi-b+

I believe the preferred way to connect to MySQL database from Python is with [MySQLdb](http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/introduction.html).

I'm relatively new to Python programming and it also seemed to be advised to write for Python 3, so I've been doing so.

But I can't see a python 3 package for mysqldb.

`apt-cache show python-mysqldb` says:

```
Depends: python (>= 2.6.6-7~), python (<< 2.8),
```

And

```
apt-cache search python3 | grep mysql
```

Gives no results.

How do I get started? Do I have to back-port my code to the old python? Thanks.

### Edit after question was closed

So I thought this was to do with the Raspian repos not having the full complement of software, but it's just a Python thing and not related to RPI, so the editors were right to close the question.

However, if you've come across this, a great answer has been [posed on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724855/623519) before.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip3
sudo pip3 install pymysql
```

Is what I went with.

Comment: Raspbian is a form of Debian, and I agree with one of your comments re, [at a glance](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mysql+python&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) for `python3` there seems only to be the "pure python" `mysql.connector` package.  However, I recommend you investigate the significance of this at our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) (WRT Debian packages) or the parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) (WRT python 3 & mysql).

Answer (score 1):

You need to know there are marked differences between Python 2 and Python 3.  A script which works in one language may not work in the other.

Python 3 specific packages have names starting with python3.

python3-pymysql may be what you want.

Try

sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql

Comment: Hmm. I don't have that package in my deb sources. Maybe I need to upgrade? I started on Wheezy

Comment: I'm afraid I tend to forget I use jessie.  Try "apt-cache search mysql | grep python" (I see you have done a similar search).

Comment: Yeah, I'm upgrading to Jessie but still there's only `python3-mysql.connector`. I'll try that.